# Dispatching requests from a servlet to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, requestdispatcher

I have a jsp page which display some records in a table and each record has a link called update next to it. When update is clicked , the jsp page will call a servlet which gets some information from the url , such as the record ownername , record title , etc. (When the link is clicked , these information are attached to url).

The servlet which is called by the jsp page , will then dispatch its request and response to another jsp page , it will display "OK". (This is just a simple program which i have setup)

My problem is, the sevlet cannot dispatch to the other jsp page.

Here is what i have done :

This is the First Jsp page which will display the records (Works perfectly)

```
<body>
    <table border="10">
        <th>Project Owner</th><th>Project Supervisor </th>
        <th>Project Title</th> 
        <th>Project Description</th>
        <th>Start-Date</th>
        <th>End-Date</th>
        <th>Approval Status</th>
        <c:forEach items="${nominationList}" var="Iter">
            <tr>
                <td>${Iter.projectOwner}</td>
                <td>${Iter.projectSupervisor}</td>
                <td>${Iter.projectTitle}</td>
                <td>${Iter.projectDescription}</td> 
                <td>${Iter.startDate}</td>
                <td>${Iter.endDate}</td>
                <td>${Iter.acceptStatus}</td>
                <td><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ProjectApproval/${Iter.projectOwner}">Update</a></td>
            </tr>  //Above is the link to update each record           
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</body>
```

This is the servlet code which it will call

```
      RequestDispatcher updateDispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("testing.jsp");
      updateDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

//this servlet dispatches to the other jsp page

I found that if i remove the extra things in the url to update (In first jsp page code) , it works but the problem is i need those extra things to implement something else in the future.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: you want to pass `${Iter.projectOwner}` as parameters to jsp?

Comment: no i want to attach it to the url and then pass it to the servlet, for a future implementation.

Comment: Attach what? to the URL?

Comment: I have already attached it to the url and passed but then, the servlet is not able to dispatch to the jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If to my understanding , when you are trying to pass the
>   **${Iter.projectOwner}**

Because you are iterating it from a list. So the data must be available in the list.

You can try an hidden field instead 
 like this ,

```
<input type="hidden" name="" value="${Iter.projectOwner}"
```

And use it in the form you are posting. .Hope it helps !

Comment: yes am trying to pass the projectOwner with the url and yes its in the list.

Is there a way to achieve this task without changing this mechanism(attaching to the url).

Thanks

Comment: @Shehan.W you can then use the above method , use the hidden field with name projectOwner . get the value in the servlet and do whatever u need with it.